# How do I find and replace a set of existing td background images in javascript without an id or name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image

I was given 1000 or so pages that were hard-coded with:

```
<TD style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(_layouts/images/content2_top_left.JPG); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat"></TD>

<TD style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(_layouts/images/content2_top_middle.jpg); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-x; HEIGHT: 8px"></TD>

<TD style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(_layouts/images/content2_top_right.JPG); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat"></TD>
```

There is no ID or Name in the table tag either. I want to swap these images when an existing script loads so that I don't have to manually change every page.

I tried using

```
document.querySelectorAll("td").item(25).style.backgroundImage = "url(_layouts/images/content2_top_left.png)";
```

That works in some instances, but the TD is not in the same place in each page, and is in multiple places in some pages. Is there an easy way to locate and replace the image? I do have jQuery loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[]` and then loop through each item of the array to change background?

Comment: so you just want to change `.jpg` to `.png`?

Answer (score 1):

That can be solve with the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
//Example for top only
$('[style*="content2_top_middle"]').css('background-image', 'url(_layouts/images/content2_top_left.png)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what Karl-André posted, you can also use a switch statement:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    switch ($('td').css('background-image')) {
        case 'url(_layouts/images/content2_top_left.JPG)':
            //do something using $(this) as your object of choice
            break;

        case 'url(_layouts/images/content2_top_middle.jpg)':
            //do something...
            break;

        case 'url(_layouts/images/content2_top_right.JPG)':
            //do something...
            break;
    }
});
```